# IE jquery doesn't allow arguments for show() in iframe

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe

I have JS code like so:

```
var li = $("li[attribute=foo]");
if (li.length)
{
  li.show("slow"); // Fails
}
```

I see:

```
Error: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

`show()` with no arguments works.

Same for `fadeIn()` or `scrollUp()`.  I've also noticed `closest()` fail on another element.  All these work in Firefox.

I'm suspicious that this is because the content in question is within an iframe (jquery itself is included in the outer page), but all other jquery in the iframe works, and from the IE debugger's point of view, the li exists and has a show method available with arguments.

Any ideas what's going wrong, or how to work around this, would be much appreciated.

Comment: What version of jQuery? (i.e. what does `alert($().jquery);` show when run in the iFrame?) And does `li.show(500);` work?

Comment: @Matt I'm using JQuery 1.4.4, IE8 - and li.show(500) fails in the same way.

Comment: Hrm. This [jQuery bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6437?cversion=0&cnum_hist=14) shows similar symptoms in IE8, but it never really got bottomed-out. Don't suppose you've got the page declared as UTF-8, but without a `Content-Type` header that declares a charset, have you? Can you narrow your code down to a small example that shows the problem, so I can try to reproduce it? I have IE8 here, at least.

Comment: Also, consider upgrading (at least temporarily) to a recent version of jQuery; 1.6.2 is the current production release, and I'd expect there to have been many IE8/workarounds fixes since 1.4.4 came out.

Comment: @Matt Good ideas.  I'm now going to try and isolate down the problem into a smaller complete example of the failure, which I'll post if I manage to create it.  From first looks, the iframe is a red herring.

Comment: @Matt I've traced it at last, mainly from stepping through the jquery code in the IE debugger.  Elsewhere on my page is an `Object.prototype.someCustomFunction` function, which the jquery `Sizzle.filter` function is trying to look at whilst iterating through the `ATTR`, `CHILD`, `CLASS`, etc Variants.

Comment: Well, I had a feeling it would be something particularly odd. If you've found a solution, I'd post your own finding as an answer; might help some other poor soul later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments above, this was nothing to do with the version of jquery or the iframe, but was because of some JS on my page in the form:

```
Object.prototype.someCustomFunction = function( aObjects ) { ...}
```

It's worth sharing how I solved this in case it helps anyone.  The secret was to get the full version of jquery, not the obfuscated and compressed one, so I could debug more easily what was going wrong in jquery.

What I found was that in `Sizzle.filter`, jquery iterates like so:

```
for ( var type in Expr.filter ) { 
    if ( (match = Expr.leftMatch[ type ].exec( expr )) != null && match[2] ) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The point is that jquery is expecting to find `ATTR`, `CHILD`, `CLASS` etc as the `type`.  But it also finds `someCustomFunction`.  And `someCustomFunction` doesn't have an `exec`, so it falls over.

The hack fix for now is to just introduce an empty `exec` method for jquery to find.  e.g.

```
Object.prototype.someCustomFunction.exec = function( expr ) {}
```

Longer term, I'll want to restrict `someCustomFunction` to where it's actually required, rather than just `Object`.